# how to load a html page inside another web page in master detail/flow in android

Tags: android, webview, master-detail

I have encountered a problem which i'm unable to solve, I googled a lot but couldn't find a solution.

I made an app using master detail/flow. This app opens a webpage whenever a category item is selected but when i click another link in the webpage it redirects to browser and opens the link in the browser. Is there a way to open all the links in the app itself?
All help is much appreciated! I'm all out of ideas here.
Thank you.

**WebpageDetailFragment.java**

```
public class WebpageDetailFragment extends Fragment {

    public static final String ARG_ITEM_ID = "item_id";

    private DummyContent.DummyItem mItem;

    public WebpageDetailFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (getArguments().containsKey(ARG_ITEM_ID)) {
            mItem = DummyContent.ITEM_MAP.get(getArguments().getString(ARG_ITEM_ID));

            Activity activity = this.getActivity();
            CollapsingToolbarLayout appBarLayout = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) activity.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_layout);
            if (appBarLayout != null) {
                appBarLayout.setTitle(mItem.item_name);
            }
        }
    }



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.webpage_detail, container, false);

        // Show the dummy content as text in a TextView.
        if (mItem != null) {
            ((WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.detail_area)).loadUrl(mItem.url);
        }
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

I have another Problem when I add your code the same page is load in the WebView the problem of redirecting to the browser is solved but it's not loading the required page. Here my code:-

**DummyContent.java**

```
public class DummyContent {

    public static final List<DummyItem> ITEMS = new ArrayList<>();

    public static final Map<String, DummyItem> ITEM_MAP = new HashMap<>();

    static {
       addItem(new DummyItem("1", "Home", "http://techonaclick.com/"));
        addItem(new DummyItem("2", "About Us", "http://techonaclick.com/about-2/"));
        addItem(new DummyItem("3", "Contact Us", "http://techonaclick.com/contact-us/"));
        addItem(new DummyItem("4", "Disclaimer", "http://techonaclick.com/disclaimer/"));
        addItem(new DummyItem("5", "Privacy Policy", "http://techonaclick.com/privacy-policy/"));
    }

    private static void addItem(DummyItem item) {
        ITEMS.add(item);
        ITEM_MAP.put(item.id, item);
    }

    public static class DummyItem {
        public final String id;
        public final String item_name;
        public final String url;

        public DummyItem(String id, String item_name, String url) {
            this.id = id;
            this.item_name = item_name;
            this.url = url;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return item_name;
        }
    }
}
```

[The place where i inserted your code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1IWg.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a new `WebViewClient()` to your main `WebView` to handle all the links.

From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html):

> When the user clicks a link from a web page in your WebView, the
>   default behavior is for Android to launch an application that handles
>   URLs. Usually, the default web browser opens and loads the destination
>   URL. However, you can override this behavior for your WebView, so
>   links open within your WebView. You can then allow the user to
>   navigate backward and forward through their web page history that's
>   maintained by your WebView.

---

*Example:*

```
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
});
```

---

*In your case:*

**Add** this snippet in any place within your `Fragment` class:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    WebView webView = (WebView) view.getRootView().findViewById(R.id.detail_area);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: As i am using Master detail/flow layout, i am not able to figure out where to add this method!

Comment: Could you please paste your code in the question? I'll add it for you.